# Add custom HTML into my view

Tags: theming

so I have a content-type `X` and a view which gets all nodes of this type. In the view I get all the fields I want and display all items in a list. I'd now like to have social sharing buttons. All modules which do that are just enabling it for the display of the content-type, I can't use it as a field itself.

So I though about just creating my own little HTML for my sharing buttons and just implement it somehow as a field, so I can place and style it like I want. [Wheras a module might bebetter but I just can't wrap my head around how to display it outside of the node's display]

So, can someone tell me how I can achieve that?

Comment: add a global Custom text field inside view and place your html there

Comment: Or to tack it onto an existing field you can edit the views field and add your content in the "Rewrite results" section which has the replacement token for the existing field value and then you can insert the rest of your code

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to use a node display instead of fields.
So first create a new node-display (if you want to use anything else then node teaser), set the fields display correctly, and create a template file.

Then alter your view so it takes the node-display instead of fields.